# Confirmation Dialog with radio buttons using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a very basic confirmation dialog that have 2 buttons:"Ok" & "Cancel".
Here is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/VQmAm/11/

Now I need to add to that confirmation dialog:
some radio buttons and the user would select only one of these values and I would take that value to use it later.

I have found set of ways to do that other than JQuery, but I was wondering if I can do that via JQuery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the radio buttons (with same `name` attribute) to the #confirmDialog div.
Then, you can get the selected value with the OK button:

```
        'OK': function() {
            value = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
            $(this).remove();
        },
```

Note that you get the value before removing the dialog. And you should define the var `value` outside the function.